# How to call some portion of an image in img tag for the image slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created an image in which small logos are combined. Now i want to use this image in an image tag and put it into image slider. I've write down all the style, script and code using for slider. But it is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://bdppl.com/bdsupport/crawler.js" ></script>
<style>
.r1, .r2, .r3, .r4, .r5, .r6, .r7, .r8 {width:100px; height:0; margin:10px; border:1px solid #212121; padding:67px 0 0 0; display:block;}
.r2{padding:67px 0 0 100px;}
.r3{padding:67px 0 0 200px; }
.r4{padding:67px 0 0 300px; }
</style>
<div id="mycrawler2">
<img class="r1" src="images/recruiters.jpg" style="background-image: url(images/recruiters.jpg)" />
<img class="r2" src="images/recruiters.jpg" style="background-image: url(images/recruiters.jpg)" />
<img class="r3" src="images/recruiters.jpg" style="background-image: url(images/recruiters.jpg)" />
<img class="r4" src="images/recruiters.jpg" style="background-image: url(images/recruiters.jpg)" />
<img class="r5" src="images/recruiters.jpg" style="background-image: url(images/recruiters.jpg)" />
<img class="r6" src="images/recruiters.jpg" style="background-image: url(images/recruiters.jpg)" />
<img class="r7" src="images/recruiters.jpg" style="background-image: url(images/recruiters.jpg)" />
<img class="r8" src="images/recruiters.jpg" style="background-image: url(images/recruiters.jpg)" />
    </div> 
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
marqueeInit({
    uniqueid: 'mycrawler2',
    style: {
        'padding': '2px',
        'width': '980px',
        'height': '100px',
        'margin': '10px 0 0 10px '
    },
    inc: 5, //speed - pixel increment for each iteration of this marquee's movement
    mouse: 'cursor driven', //mouseover behavior ('pause' 'cursor driven' or false)
    moveatleast: 2,
    neutral: 150,
    savedirection: true,
    random: true
});
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make blank image in png format and then give its path. Modify old style with current style in css.

```
<style>
    .m1, .m2, .m3, .m4, .m5, .m6, .m7, .m8, .m9, .m10, .m11, .m12, .m13, .m14, .m15, .m16, .m17, .m18, .m19, .m20 {width:100px; height:67px; margin:10px; border:1px solid #212121; background:url(../images/recruiters.jpg);}
    .m2{background-position: 100px 0;}
    .m3{background-position: 200px 0;}
    .m4{background-position: 300px 0;}
    .m5{background-position: 400px 0;}
    .m6{background-position: 500px 0;}
    .m7{background-position: 600px 0;}
    .m8{background-position: 700px 0;}
    .m9{background-position: 800px 67px;}
    .m10{background-position:900px 67px;}
    .m11{background-position: 0 67px;}
    .m12{background-position: 100px 67px;}
    .m13{background-position: 200px 67px;}
    .m14{background-position: 300px 67px;}
    .m15{background-position: 400px 67px;}
    .m16{background-position: 500px 67px;}
    .m17{background-position: 600px 67px;}
    .m18{background-position: 700px 67px;}
    .m19{background-position: 800px 67px;}
    .m20{background-position: 900px 67px;}
    </style>
    <div id="mycrawler2">
    <img class="m1" src="images/n.png" alt="" />
    <img class="m2" src="images/n.png" alt="" />
    <img class="m3" src="images/n.png" alt="" />
    <img class="m4" src="images/n.png" alt="" />
    <img class="m5" src="images/n.png" alt="" />
    <img class="m6" src="images/n.png" alt="" />
    <img class="m7" src="images/n.png" alt="" />
    <img class="m8" src="images/n.png" alt="" />
    <img class="m9" src="images/n.png" alt="" />
    <img class="m10" src="images/n.png" alt="" />
    <img class="m11" src="images/n.png" alt="" />
    <img class="m12" src="images/n.png" alt="" />
    <img class="m13" src="images/n.png" alt="" />
    <img class="m14" src="images/n.png" alt="" />
    <img class="m15" src="images/n.png" alt="" />
    <img class="m16" src="images/n.png" alt="" />
    <img class="m17" src="images/n.png" alt="" />
    <img class="m18" src="images/n.png" alt="" />
    <img class="m19" src="images/n.png" alt="" />
    <img class="m20" src="images/n.png" alt="" />
    </div>
```